# Pasar datos de html a componente

Tags: angular

tengo este html

```
<div class="horizontal">
    <div>
        <span>  <input type="text" maxlength="100" placeholder="titulo" name="name">   </span>
        <span>  <input type="date" name="date">   </span>
    </div>

    <span> <input type="button" id="send" name="more" (click)="saveBooks(name.value, date.value)" value="Send"></span>
    <!-- (click)="changeList(true) -->
</div>
```

y en el componente de angular tengo

```
async saveBooks(name, date){
        console.log('DATE ', name, date);
    }
```

obtengo el siguiente error:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (DatasComponent.html:22)
    at handleEvent (core.js:23107)
```

Comment: No entiendo de Angular, pero al parecer `name` es un nombre reservado, intenta cambiarlo por `name2`... En vez de `async` me parece que va `async function`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No hace falta enviar datos desde parametro, debes usar ng.model

te dejo un ejemplo

en el .html

```
<span>  <input type="text" maxlength="100" placeholder="titulo" name="book" [(ngModel)]="valueBook">   </span>
<span>  <input type="date" name="date" [(ngModel)]="valueDate">   </span>
```

en el .component

```
private valueBook: string;
private valueDate: string;
async saveBooks(){
        console.log( this.valueBook, this.valueDate);
}
```

De esa manera las variables `valueBook` y `valueDate` estan enlazadas la vista con el componente